# SAPUI5 - Read dynamically created form

Tags: forms, sapui5

I have a form with SegmentedButtons and InputFields which I create dynamically with an XML model. The user now has the ability to make inputs and selections. 
Now I want to collect and send the input and selections in the easiest way.
What is the best way to do this?

XMLview

```
<form:SimpleForm editable="true" id="fCheckList">
<List id="lCheckList" items="{List>/Rowset/Row/}" >
    <InputListItem>
        <SegmentedButton    selectedItem="none" 
                            items="{path:'List>Selection/Row/', templateShareable: true}" 
                            visible="{= ${List>Type} === 'segmented'}" 
                            selectionChange="onSegBtnSelected">
            <items>
                <SegmentedButtonItem key="{List>ID}" text="{List>Value}" />
            </items>
        </SegmentedButton>

        <Input value="" visible="{= ${List>Type} === 'input' }" />
    </InputListItem>
</List>
```

Comment: What kind of model do you use? Is 'List' a JSONModel or ODataModel?

Comment: I use a XMLModel.

Comment: Then unless you are not using the default twoway binding of the XMLModel you should be just able to query the model data in your controller.